# Bot not responding to messages in Bot Framework Emulator due to QnAMaker connection issue

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

My chatbot uses QnAMaker to respond to questions from the user. Recently this has stopped working when I'm testing in the Bot Framework Emulator. The bot is functioning perfectly in Web Chat however. I believe the issue occurs when I try to generate an answer from my QnAMaker Knowledge Base:

```
var response = await botServices.QnAServices[QnAMakerName].GetAnswersAsync(stepContext.Context, qnaMakerOptions);
```

This is the output I am getting in the console:

```
fail: Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.QnABot[0]
      Exception caught : System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
         at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacketAsync(Stream transport, AsyncProtocolRequest request)
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
         at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
         at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
         at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.HttpRequestUtils.ExecuteHttpRequestAsync(String requestUrl, String payloadBody, QnAMakerEndpoint endpoint) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA\Utils\HttpRequestUtils.cs:line 64
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.GenerateAnswerUtils.QueryQnaServiceAsync(Activity messageActivity, QnAMakerOptions options) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA\Utils\GenerateAnswerUtils.cs:line 212
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.GenerateAnswerUtils.GetAnswersRawAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IMessageActivity messageActivity, QnAMakerOptions options) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA\Utils\GenerateAnswerUtils.cs:line 87
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.QnAMaker.GetAnswersRawAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, QnAMakerOptions options, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA\QnAMaker.cs:line 198
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA.QnAMaker.GetAnswersAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, QnAMakerOptions options, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.QnA\QnAMaker.cs:line 158
         at X.Dialogs.QnAMakerDialog.CallGenerateAnswer(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\X\Desktop\X\Dialogs\QnAMakerDialog.cs:line 239
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.OnStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 175
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.RunStepAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 index, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 197
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 82
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 170
         at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.QnABot.DispatchToTopIntentAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IList`1 intent, RecognizerResult recognizerResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\X\Desktop\X\QnAMaker\QnABot.cs:line 171
         at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.QnABot.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\X\Desktop\X\QnAMaker\QnABot.cs:line 136
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 1252
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
         at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 200
```

Testing in the emulator always worked fine up until now. Anyone know how to solve?

Comment: Are you able to do to qnamaker.ai and chat with it there?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? If so, can you share what version of the Bro Framework Emulator you're using?

Comment: @AskYous Yeah, still having this problem. V4.7.0 I'm using. When the problem began I was using an older version and then updated. Same issue in both versions.

Comment: Dang... really not sure. I would try it on a different machine, so we can rule out it being an internet issue with your computer. Otherwise, I'm really not sure.

Comment: does it work as expected in 'Test in Web Chat' on Azure or any other channel?

Comment: @ranusharao Yes it's working as expected

Comment: @AskYous I tried this out and got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

One item that can cause this is if your development configuration is different from your Azure configuration. Please compare your `QnAEndpointHostName`, `QnAEndpointKey`, and `QnAKnowledgebaseId` to see if they differ between local and Azure.

If you've done anything different with local config lately, verify where those credentials are coming from. e.g. ASP.NET appSettings, secrets manager, or environment.

Also, since some of the stack trace is working with SSL types, you might want to double check that you're `QnAEndpointHostName` has an `https` protocol prefix.

Comment: I double checked to be sure, but development config and Azure config match up. And `QnAEndpointHostName` has an `https` protocol prefix. No changes have been made to the local version since I last published so I'm really not sure what the issue is.